# How not to mess up styling when using css frameworks

Tags: css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Google Maps API V3 with Twitter Bootstrap and here's what I got. The marker can't even be recognized as a marker and the zooming tool is gone. 
[image]

It seems like Twitter boostrap is messing up the styling of the map canvas is there a way on how to exclude an element from being styled by a certain framework? Or just simply reset the styling on only the map canvas so that it doesn't get affected by the stylesheet for twitter bootstrap?

Here's some code aside from the styling from twitter bootstrap:

```
<style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body{ height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you post a live demo of this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe it has to do with them adding

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

suggested fix was this:

```
#mapContainer img{
    max-width: none;
}
```

see here https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1552

**[update]**

Looks like the release of 2.0.4 should resolve this issue (*I've not tried it just going by change.log*)

http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2012/06/bootstrap-2-0-4-released/

Comment: I've gone ahead and tried it on the Chrome console:
$('img').css('max-width','100%')
It seems to have no effect but I'll try adding that to my code

Comment: you want the opposite of that since they're already setting all images to `max-width: 100%` you need to nullify it. `$('img').css({'max-width': 'none'})`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `Bootstrap + Google Maps`. I'm assuming that your are using additional CSS files (added in your  after bootstrap files), so in order to "overwrite" that style in the images contained in the #map container, justo use something like the code below in your own CSS files:

```
#mapContainer img{
    max-width: none;
}
```

Just like subhaze said. It worked well for me.

Hope this helps you.